# Pandas create column from another dataframe if certain conditions match

Tags: python, pandas

Hey all I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe based on if certain conditions are meet. The end goal is go have all rows that condition is unoccupied in a column as long as the building, floor, and location matches. And time is greater then the occupied time.

[Sample CSV File](https://ufile.io/d8mkh)

I tried looking at this beforehand but I don't believe that it fits what I am trying to do. [Other Stack Overflow Post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19227/create-a-new-column-based-on-two-columns-from-two-different-dataframes)

Would love to get pointed into the right direction for this.

current code that I am playing around with: (Also attempted with a loop but I no longer have the code to post it below)

```
[from IPython.display import display
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/username/Desktop/test.csv")

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df2['Location'] = df.Location
df2['Type'] = df.Type
df2['Floor'] = df.Floor
df2['Building'] = df.Building
df2['Time'] = df['Date/Time']
df2['Status'] = df['Status']

df2 = df[~df['Condition'].isin(['Unoccupied'])]
df2['Went Unoccupied'] = np.where((df2['Location']==df['Location'])&(df2['Time'] < df['Date/Time']))
```

Comment: df2['Went Unoccupied']=(df2['Time'] < df['Date/Time']) ?

Comment: @Wen that spits out: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: @scarecrow I don't really know what you mean by "The end goal is go have all rows that condition is unoccupied in a column as long as the building, floor, and location matches. And time is greater then the occupied time." Can you just give us some sample input and output here?

Comment: @Tai here you go! Input file: https://ufile.io/ehirb and output file:
 https://ufile.io/66l9k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP tried to add the unoccupied time for each row that has `Condition == occupied`. It seems the data is well sorted and alternates between occupied and unoccupied. Thus, we shift the dataset backward and create a new column `time_of_next_row`. Then, query for the condition that `df1.Condition == "Occupied"`.

```
df["time_of_next_row"] = df.shift(-1)["Date/Time"]
df_occ = df1[df1.Condition == "Occupied"]
```

Comment: what would be a more flexible way of doing this?

Comment: @scarecrow Think you should group your data by room and sort by time?. and then if the data is in order like your example dataset, you can use the method I listed.

Comment: thanks! thats all i needed to know. Thank you for the help im relatively new to actually try to transform data like this. Out of curiosity, why cant i do df_occ = df1[df1.Condition == "Occupied" and df1.Type == "Conference Room"]? It spits out a bool error

Comment: @scarecrow No problem. Glad to help.